# Threejs Get raycaster intersection near objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm trying to get the objects that are 'near' the mouse, i'm using the following:

```
raycaster.near = 10;
raycaster.far = 100;
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

        console.log(intersects);

    }

} else {

    //Manage mouse out

}
```

It ignores the near and far properties and just get the objects right under the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

the `near` and `far` properties indicate the distance along the ray, not the distance from it. So in your case the raycaster will match objects between 10 and 100 units away from the camera, not a radius around the ray.

As far as I know, a tolerance-value like you are looking for is not available in the raycaster. What you can do though, is to create an separate scene only for the raycasting. For every object that needs raycasting you would then create another object (scaled up by some factor) and add that to the raycasting-scene.